# Can you use an intent to launch Adobe Reader or the Docs Reader to open an specific PDF in an Android machine?

Tags: android, android-intent, google-docs, adobe-reader

On a site targeting Android OS, is there a way to create a link that will cause the OS to open a PDF that was downloaded from that site? That is, without requiring the user to manually open the PDF?

EDIT: to clarify, I want to implement something similar to this on my site:

```
<a href="adobe_reader/foo.pdf">Click here to open foo.pdf on your Android!</a>
```

This is supposed to be a link on my site that makes Adobe (or another) to launch `foo.pdf`, which is already stored on the android device.

Answer (score 1):

They should.  Try this:

```
                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                intent.setDataAndType(path, "application/pdf");
                startActivity(intent);
```

If any app has registered to be able to view PDFs (and both of those should have), it will launch them.  Or any other app installed that claims to be able to read pdfs.

Comment: I think I expressed myself wrong. I mean a link-like intent launcher. Like, I want to launch the PDF reader for a file FROM a site. For example: <a href="adobe/foo.pdf">click here</a> causing "click here" to launch adobe reader for "foo.pdf" (which is previously stored on the device).

Comment: Ah.  That needs to be handled by the browser.  In fact I'm surprised it isn't-  I've had files ask me if I wanted to launch them in certain apps before.

Answer (score 0):

You can use combination of WebView and Google Docs
Try this :

You can try using a combination of

```
String docName = "somedoc.pdf"
String PDF_BASE_URL = "http://docs.google.com/gview?embedded=true&url=";
mWebView.loadUrl(PDF_BASE_URL + docName);
```

Answer (score 0):

## Oh, I understand its a site

I think what you've done is sufficient, as the browsers deal with how they want to handle links. What you've done should work on most browsers if not the stock browser on android.